# error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)' c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
void print(int ia[])
{
    int *p = begin(ia);
    while(p != end(ia))
        cout<<*p++<<'\t';
}

int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4},i;
    print(ia);

    return 0;
}
```

P pointer to the first element in ia.
why it said"error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)' c++"
thanks!:)

Comment: @KarthikT: It would make no difference.  Calling `begin` on a pointer won't ever work.

Comment: @EdS. ah yes.. why didnt i see that..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because inside `print()`, the variable `ia` is a pointer, not an array.  It doesn't make sense to call `begin()` on a pointer.

Comment: I know it's an old post, but why does the error say "... for call to 'begin(int*&)'" and  not "... for call to 'begin(int*)"?

Comment: Because lvalues are passed as references.

Answer (score 9):

You are using the `begin` and `end` free functions on a pointer, that's not allowed.

You can do something similar with C++11's `intializer_list`

```
//g++ -std=c++0x test.cpp -o test
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
void print(initializer_list<int> ia)
{
    auto p = begin(ia);
    while(p != end(ia))
        cout<<*p++<<'\t';
}

int main()
{
    print({1,2,3,4});   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd also suggest use range-based for.

Answer (score 8):

As others pointed out, your array is decaying to a pointer. Decaying is historical artifact from C. To do what you want, pass array as reference and deduce array size:

```
template<size_t X>
void print(int (&ia)[X])
{
    int *p = begin(ia);
    while(p != end(ia))
        cout<<*p++<<'\t';
}

print(ia);
```