# Function taking a raw pointer tries to accept the pointer by reference as outlined in error msg

Tags: c++, function, pointers

While looking for some help with a problem of mine, I've found this post: [error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)' c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848192/error-no-matching-function-for-call-to-beginint-c)

I get it why there's an error there, but why does it say "... for call to 'begin(int*&)'" and not "... for call to 'begin(int*)"? It looks to me like the ia pointer is being passed by value and not reference.

Just for reference (no pun intended) - the following code didn't compile with the message *no matching function for call to 'begin(int*&)':

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;
void print(int ia[])
{
    int *p = begin(ia);
    while(p != end(ia))
        cout<<*p++<<'\t';
}

int main()
{
    int ia[] = {1,2,3,4},i;
    print(ia);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's just because you're using an lvalue - so the compiler is looking for a function that takes its argument by reference *as its first choice*.  It doesn't mean that it won't also consider copying the argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since no matching function could be found, the compiler tells you the specific types of the parameters being passed as that's the only information it has to work with. Since you have a named lvalue here it's first assumption is that you're passing by reference and so that's what the diagnostic message prints.

If for example you had passed a literal there would be no way for a reference function to be correct so it would assume you were passing by value.

Answer (score 0):

For me the code above compiles with the same error:

```
'no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)'
```

And what is more important:

```
error: request for member ‘begin’ in ‘__cont’, which is of non-class type ‘int*’
```

Take a look at the std::begin signature: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin

In your example template ia will be int* as array gets implicitly converted. Next take a look link above and see that all signatures that are not arrays has:
`-> decltype(c.begin()`).